# Rails: add an action to a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, routes

I am creating an app with users. My `UsersController` has a `show` method. Thus, user with `id = 1` can be reached at `/users/1`.

My `routes.rb` file contains `:users` resources. Thus, `/users/1/edit` renders the `edit` page for user with `id = 1`.

What I am trying to accomplish is creating a new action, which allows one to put a request for any user by reaching `/users/USER_ID/request`.

How do I do that? Appreciate the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a following route (`routes.rb`):

```
get '/users/:id/request' => 'users#request', as: :user_request
```

Second, add a `request` method to `UsersController`:

```
def request
  @user = User.find params[:id]
  # do your thing
end
```

You can create a link to this URL in your views like so: `<%= link_to 'Request', user_request_path(@user.id) %>`

Comment: Could you flag my answer as accepted? This will make it easier for people with a similar problem to find a solution quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean "controller within a controller". The above request should be possible by passing a block to your `resources` route.

However, it's very dangerous to use "request" as an action name since `request` is a commonly used method in action controller:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
   put :process_request, on: :member
end
```

**Users Controller:**

```
def process_request
   # ...
end
```